# If I make an object in code, can I refer to it later to make changes?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm looking to build as much of my new app in code rather than in interface builder as much of it will involve making several recurring views. I'm hoping however to be able to come back to many of the objects that I am making as possible to interact with them later.

Do all of these objects need to be created in my .h files and then set up in my .m, or can I build them only when I need to? Would it not be better for memory if I were only to create the objects when I need them?

For example, I can make a UIView in one method like so:

```
-(void)makeViewOne {
UIView *viewOne = [[UIView alloc] init];
viewOne.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[mainView addSubview:viewOne];
}

-(void)changeViewOneBackgroundColor {
viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

But then in a second method, how would I be able to refer back to this view? I'd also like to build and refer back to things such as UITextFields, UILabels, UIButtons and so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you heard of `ivars` or `@property`'s? You need to store the views you want into either of the two.

Comment: You can store pointers to your created objects anywhere you want to.  ivars and properties are the conventional choices, but you can also us an NSArray or an NSDictionary.  Or you can even navigate from the main view, querying it to find IDs or whatever you need to zero in on your target object (though this approach is slow and messy).

Comment: I have, but haven't come across them much in my (limited) previous work. As such, I had no idea to look into these but will do more research in this area.

Comment: The answer was edited in, so I removed it from the original question as it belongs in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods to achieve this, here's just one of them that I typically use:

Note: This example uses an internal property to hold a reference to your view.  The key lesson in this was mentioned by *HotLicks* and *tom* in your comments, that you may use ivars and properties(among other things):

***MyViewController.m***

```
@interface MyViewController()
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *viewOne;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize viewOne;
...
...
-(void)makeViewOne 
{
    self.viewOne = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.viewOne.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
    self.viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [mainView addSubview:self.viewOne];
}
-(void)changeViewOneBackgroundColor 
{
    self.viewOne.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
/*
 Bonus!
*/
-(void)removeViewOne 
{
    [self.viewOne removeFromSuperview];
}
...
...
@end
```

**EDIT**

To be clear, the point is to save a reference to your view somewhere.  In the comments, you mention that you may have multiple objects, or may not depending on your situation.  This doesn't change anything; however, you may instead consider storing your views in a collection, again pointed out by HotLicks.  But, to do that, you will need to store a reference to your collection somewhere as well in order to obtain its contents.  So, using my example, you may then decide to instead create a property of type `NSMutableDictionary` or `NSMutableArray`, or various other types, and then add whatever views you wish to create in them.  Using a `NSMutableDictionary` may be more useful to you as you may store your views in them with a key, then to refer back to those views with the key.

Another possibility, assuming you have a reference to `mainView` is to set the tag property of each of your views, or some custom property.  Then, you can enumerate `mainView.subviews` to obtain the view you are looking for in order to make changes to it.

Comment: Answer provided above is correct, however just to copy and paste it is no good. This is fundamental part of how you code on iOS and you really need to understand at dept how and why are these things done. Otherwise you are wandering in the dark. I would strongly recommend you to look at this free iTunesU course https://itunes.apple.com/gb/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016. It is thought by Paul Hegarty, he worked at Next when they developed what would later become OS X. You could hardly get better person to explain how it all works.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I am a little unsure about this though. It looks like, from the top part of your code, that this is similar what I have done in the past using a .h file and was hoping to avoid.

The idea is that the items are created only if they are needed. I'd like to make a view for each player in a game, and would rather not have have to either make a lot of views on the off chance that they are needed and have them being un-used, or find myself in a position where I don't have enough.
This is where my goal to make them as-needed came from.

Comment: That's up to you Alan and is completely contingent on your skill level.  But, the message to be gleaned from the example is to store a reference _somewhere_ so that you can refer back to it.  If an ivar or property is not your bag, then, as HotLicks pointed out, you may use arrays or dictionaries.  I'll update the answer with an alternative.

Comment: @stringCode - I may have mis-worded my question slightly. I understand everything that Jeremy has provided in the answer but it doesn't solve the problem that I am trying to tackle.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, I guess I need to look more into that so that I can add into the array/dictionary as I make the views.